# When it does not fit at the end of a line, can I hyphenate 'limitations' as 'limitation-s'?

Tags: hyphens

Is it correct to hyphen limitations as 'limitation-s' ?

According to [this](http://www.spell-check-thesaurus.com/en/limitations.aspx) site it is wrong as it is hyphenated as: 'lim-i-ta-tions'.

It is also wrong according to [hunspell](http://www.ushuaia.pl/hyphen/?ln=en), which says that the correct forms are 'lim-i-ta-tions' (en-us dict) or 'lim-it-a-tions' (en-gb dict).

But I just found the (limitation-s) form in a text and I was wondering if there is a rule which allows this form or not.

Comment: No, that hyphenation is not acceptable.

Comment: That hyphenation violates 2 rules: "Never split in the middle of a syllable" and "Never split less than 3 letters."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments:

> That hyphenation violates 2 rules: "Never split in the middle of a syllable" and "Never split less than 3 letters." –  [Hellion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/87/hellion) [Mar 19 2015](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53098/is-limitation-s-correct-hyphenation#comment99419_53098)

I expect it was a word across multiple lines, it didn't fit at the end of the line. See [this for information](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line). As the answer says, it *shouldn't* be hyphenated here, as it isn't a syllable break. The allowed places are here: *lim**·**i**·**ta**·**tion*